# how to prove that two sets have the same homotopy type

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I want to prove that two bounded sets $A$ and $B$ of $R^2$ have the same Euler characteristic (number of connected components minus number of connected components of the complementary) but I think that they actually have the same homotopy type (group structure for continuous paths).

In full generality, What is the most efficient way to prove that two bounded sets have the same homotopy type?

Is it enough to show for any path $\gamma:[0,1]\to A$ continuous there is $\phi:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to A$ continuous such that $\phi(0,\cdot)=\gamma$ and $\phi(1,\cdot)\in B$ (and the other way around and idem for complementary sets)?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to prove that if two bounded sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the same Euler characteristic, then they are homotopy equivalent? Or do you want to prove that any two bounded sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the same Euler characteristic (your first sentence before the "but")?

Comment: No actually I'm asking a rather general question on how to prove, in general, that two sets have the same homotopy type (for the example in which I'm interested, I already know that they have the same EC, but I know it is not going to serve me in the general proof, it's just my introduction)

Comment: "By demonstrating a homotopy equivalence". There's Whitehead's theorem, but you still need to write down a map inducing an isomorphism on all homotopy groups. In general, there is no algorithm (and it is impossible to make one) to calculate whether or not two spaces have the same homotopy type.

Comment: Indeed, my question is wether I need to exhibhit some global bijections, or just a path-by-path mapping is enough?

Comment: There are hundreds of people that have been working for decades trying to answer this question... You're going to need to be more specific if you want a good answer.

Comment: OK...I aplogize for asking a rather general question. What about the last question, is it not precise?

Comment: As $A$ and $B$ are subsets of the plane, which is contractible, the condition you have written, as it appears, holds for any two non-empty subsets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks, it is actually far from obvious to me. Would you have an idea for launching the proof, or a reference I could use? Thanks

Comment: Contract the path to a point and then drag it over to a point inside $B$.

Comment: So there is actually no need to consider paths, if I just show that every point of $B$ can be individually brought continuously to $A$ while staying in $B$, the other way around, and for complementaries, then it is enough?

Comment: 'while staying in $B$' makes things very different. I don't quite understand what you mean. Have you seen the definition of homotopy equivalent? It is very different from what you are considering. It would be helpful to think of $A$ and $B$ as separate topological spaces with the subspace topology, instead of as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes I have, and in the definition global mappings from $A$ to $B$ and from $B$ to $A$ are mentionned, while I'm interested in properties that would hold for each path. That is why I was surprised by your answer.

Comment: I suggest you try to formulate a precise question as it's not clear what you mean at all.

Comment: What is not clear about the last question in the topic?

Comment: $\phi\colon [0,1]\times [0,1]\to A$ has codomain $A$ and then you impose the condition $\phi(1,\cdot)\in B$. What does that mean for a map restricted to a particular subdomain (i.e. $\{1\}\times[0,1]$) to be an element of some different codomain?

Comment: I don't know what is a codomain, but $\phi(1,.)\in B$ means that $\phi(1,s)\in B$ for every $s\in [0,1]$, which would imply here that it would be in $A$ and $B$. (in my case $A$ is an approximation of $B$, a little bit complicated to describe here)

Comment: So is $B$ a subset of $A$?

Comment: no, why? It's just that they have a nonempty intersection

Comment: So the image of the map $\phi|_{\{1\}\times [0,1]}$ would have to be a subset of $A\cap B$, yes?

Comment: yes it is---------------- (sorry about the dots its just that a comment requires a minimal number of characters)

Comment: Ok, then the condition is satisfied precisely if the image of $\gamma$ belongs to the same path component as some point in $A\cap B$. You first shrink the path to a point, and then you drag that point along a path to some point in $A\cap B$ which lies in that path component.

Comment: Yes we seemed to have converged on the definition :) So this property could be stated with paths and not points, right? And you say it would yield a homotopy equivalence (although it is a point-by-point result)?

Comment: It wouldn't be a homotopy equivalence at all. If I have $A=S^1$ the unit circle, and $B=\{(x,y)\in A\mid y\geq 0\}$, a subinterval of the circle, the condition is satisfied but $A$ and $B$ are far from homotopy equivalent.

Comment: it is also supposed to hold from $B$ to $A$ and in both directions for complementary sets (which is not the case in your counter-example)

Comment: Ok an easier example, $A=\{0\}\times[0,1]$ and $B=\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$. The condition is satisfied in all four of those cases but $A$ and $B$ are not homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Oh I see, then my paths should be loops ($\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$), and then it might work

Comment: Loops makes things much more interesting.

Comment: In any case, what you are talking about in the third paragraph of your question has very little to do with homotopy equivalences... In general, it is rather non trivial to show that two sets have the same homotopy type. Without being more specific about what sets you have in mind, there is pretty much nothing more useful we can say that «Look for a homotopy equivalence».

Comment: Sometimes there are methods more used and faster than others for proving something. For instance for proving that a set is a manifold you can write it as a level set, for proving that a set is convex you write as an intersection of convex, etc...I was looking for something of that kind, for me it is in the spirit of stackexchange. For my third question, as I said in my comment, I should have asked for the paths to be loops, then I think it would have been relevant. Anyway thank you for your gentle answers.